# CSS Grid not showing item in specified grid column

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have an embedded form which has a three column layout.

Though the use of grids, I'm trying to get the submit button to sit in the middle (so the second column), but unsure why my current approach doesn't work:

```css
#form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'inputs1 inputs2 textarea' 'inputs1 inputs2 submit';
  justify-content: center;
  grid-auto-columns: 25%;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">

  <div class="responsiveRow">
    <span> Text 1:</span>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="responsiveRow">
    <span> Text 2:</span>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>

  <div class="responsiveRow">
    <span> Textarea:</span>
    <textarea cols="10" rows="10"> </textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="responsiveRow">
    <span> Text 3:</span>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>

  <div class="responsiveRow">
    <span> Text 4:</span>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>

  <div class="responsiveRow">
    <input type="submit">
  </div>


</form>
```

I cannot change the HTML of the form and the above is how the form code appears after embed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Desired results:

[image]

Comment: can you please attache image with your expcted output

Comment: @CRR added image :)

Comment: approach is not proper i think, check https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_grid-template-areas

Comment: have you added css, for the grid areas?

Comment: like `responsiveRow:nth-of-type(1) {grid-area: inputs1;}` etc

Comment: @Stender - No, the only CSS I have related to grids is on the `#form`. I would've assumed `grid-template-areas` would've resolved this?

Comment: @Freddy the `grid-template-areas` needs to know, what to work with - see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the grid areas, to decide where to put the items in your grid -

The following example should be what you need.

```css
.responsiveRow:nth-of-type(3) {grid-area: myArea;}
.responsiveRow:nth-of-type(6) {grid-area:centered;}
.responsiveRow{border: 1px solid #000;}
#form{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: '. . myArea' '. . myArea' '. centered .';
    justify-content: center;
    grid-auto-columns: 33%;
}

/*remove the grid on mobiles*/
@media all and (max-width:540px){
  #form{
    display:block;
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="form">

  <div class="responsiveRow">
    <span> Text 1:</span>
    <input type="text"/>
  </div>
  <div class="responsiveRow">
    <span> Text 2:</span>
    <input type="text"/>
  </div>
  
    <div class="responsiveRow">
    <span> Textarea:</span>
    <textarea cols="10" rows="10"> </textarea>
  </div>
  
    <div class="responsiveRow">
    <span> Text 3:</span>
    <input type="text"/>
  </div>
  
    <div class="responsiveRow">
    <span> Text 4:</span>
    <input type="text"/>
  </div>
  
    <div class="responsiveRow">
    <input type="submit">
  </div>
  
  
</form>
```

Comment: Added borders for visual representation

Comment: Ah thanks! a followup question, for mobile, I just want the layout to be one column. Removing `grid-template-areas` has no effect for me, how would I go about this?

Comment: @Freddy just remove grid then? - I will add it in

Comment: @Freddy I  added the CSS for mobiles for you

Comment: No, that's what I'm saying, removing grid doesn't put everything into a single column. I've even tried flex `#form {display:flex; flex-direction:column;}`

Comment: so, on your computer, my snippet is not in a single column, when on small screens? because if I make my window small, it goes into a single column here, with just display:block.

Comment: awesome - glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```css
#form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
#text-area {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}
#button {
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <div class="responsiveRow">
    <span> Text 1:</span>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="responsiveRow">
    <span> Text 2:</span>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="responsiveRow" id="text-area">
    <span> Textarea:</span>
    <textarea cols="10" rows="10"> </textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="responsiveRow">
    <span> Text 3:</span>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="responsiveRow">
    <span> Text 4:</span>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="responsiveRow" id="button">
    <input type="submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tck6fsdv/)